# Div height issue

Tags: css, html

I'm having an issue with height of a `div` element in my code.

Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/qUfr8/ 
...and now this: http://jsfiddle.net/DdUbr/

Pay attention on the red border. It's fine in the first example, but not in the second.
The only difference between those examples is that I added two `div` elements to the second code and now the height of `content` is equal to 0, but the `content` is still displayed, though.

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Ollie is correct in his answer, check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DdUbr/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a clear fix if your floating elements inside a div

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/DdUbr/2/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix it is adding "display: inline-block" to your #content:

http://jsfiddle.net/DdUbr/6/